# Django storing anonymous user data

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a django model which stores user and product data from a form input:

```
def ProductSelection(request, template_name='product_selection.html'):
    ...
    if user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user
    else:
        # deal with anonymous user info
    project = Project.objects.create(
        user=user,
        product=form.cleaned_data["product"],
        quantity=form.cleaned_data["product_quantity"],
    )
```

Of course this is fine for authenticated users, but I also want to be able to store anonymous user projects, and if possible, associate them with the user when they eventually register and authenticate.

My idea is to create anonymous user with name = some_variable (timestamp concatenated with a random hash?), then save that username in session data. If I ensure that that session variable, if exists, is used to record all projects activity of that user, I should be able to update the projects with the user's real credentials when they register.

Is this overly complicated and brittle? Do I risk saving thousands of rows of data unnecessarily? What would be the optimal approach for this common issue?

Any guidance on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use [Django's session framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) to store anonymous user data.

You can then either add a field to your `Project` model to hold the `session_key` value for anonymous users,

```
project = Project.objects.create(
    user=request.user,  # can be anonymous user
    session=request.session.session_key,
    product=form.cleaned_data["product"],
    quantity=form.cleaned_data["product_quantity"])
```

or simply store all the data a Project instance would have in the session

```
if user.is_authenticated():
    project = Project.objects.create(
        user=request.user,
        product=form.cleaned_data["product"],
        quantity=form.cleaned_data["product_quantity"])
else:
    # deal with anonymous user info
    request.session['project'] = {
        "product": form.cleaned_data["product"],
        "quantity": form.cleaned_Data["product_quantity"]}
```

You can retrieve the data from the session later, when creating a proper user.

Comment: When I've ran into similar issues in the past, the problem comes when you need to go back in the other direction. Like if users could have multiple projects, and you needed to do something like see which sessions liked two specific projects.

Comment: In my case, I want to both store the anonymous user data in the db and also associate it with a specific user through sessions. If `user=request.user` returns an anonymous user object, I can't later tie this info to the user upon registration.

Comment: In that case, my first example should do it: add a field to hold the `session_key` value and you can later retrieve the desired Project instance and relate it to the new user when the anonymous user stops being anonymous :-)

Comment: Does this support multiple objects added to cart?

Comment: @Gonzalo, dont you face problems while querying the saved key from database ?
My key never matches

Comment: @TheDoctor. sorry, I wrote that solution years ago! It's probably outdated in relation to newer Django versions. I would try to isolate the problem you're having and post a new question :)

Answer (score 13):

Just to clarify, the below code is how implemented the solution in my case:

```
        project = Project.objects.create(
            session=request.session.session_key,
            # save all other fields
            ...
        )
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            project.user = request.user
        else:
            # make a copy of the session key
            # this is done because the session_key changes
            # on login/ register 
            request.session['key_copy'] = request.session.session_key
        project.save()
```

And in my models.py:

```
 class Project(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
     ...
```

So a user field can be null, and in this case we use the session_key to keep a track of things.