# How to pass a state back to the template after logging in using Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

The use case:

The user enters a comment while not logged in. The `login_required` decorator sends them to the login page, and redirects them back to comment page, but their comment is lost.

I can do something hacky to make it work; but is there a django way, that is generic and clean, for keeping the request parameters, and passing them back, as context variables, for use in the redirecting template/form?

Comment: Why don't you use sessions?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid because they enter the comment before being logged in.

Comment: This answers my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938805/django-storing-anonymous-user-data. Thanks for the suggestion @BurhanKhalid