# Identify unique anonymous user in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, throttling

I am applying throttling in Rest apis. For registered users its working fine but for anonymous users i am not able to identify unique user with 100% certanity.

Django Rest Framework uses `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` and `REMOTE_ADDR` from http header to identify anonymous users on basis of their IP address. But it treats all clients behind a unique NAT'd as a single client.

So what is the reliable way to identify unique anonymous users so that apis can be properly throttled?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that - you will always have this problem of NAT-ed networks. It's something you cannot control - it has to do with how the network communications is functioning.. What you could do is to implement a guest mechanism, where you will attach short lived session cookies to requests. For that you will have to care to build your own middleware.

Comment: This must be the common problem for people who are working on apis and analytics because at some point they have to identify user. I just want to know what is the standard way to identify unique anonymous user ?

Comment: Well ... for the sake of the debate: if there would have been such a way to identify the requestor behind a request, wouldn't the current authentication techniques have taken advantage of that? Even if skeptical, I keep my mind open if someone knows a better answer ....

Answer (score 2):

I think you can address this with `sessions` which is the only unique field for anonymous users you can use for tracking.

Sessions are based on cookies so when your anonymous user returns to your application if cookies are still valid you will be able te retrieve the proper session for user.

I think this link can be helpful: [Django storing anonymous user data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938805/django-storing-anonymous-user-data)