# Registration of an anonymous DRF user

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I'm writing an API questionnaire on the Django Rest Framework, when passing the survey, I collect the id of an authorized user. But what about an anonymous user who has passed the survey, how do I get his unique id?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can address this with sessions which is the only unique field for anonymous users you can use for tracking.

Sessions are based on cookies so when your anonymous user returns to your application if cookies are still valid you will be able to retrieve the proper session for user.

This can be helpful for you. [Storing anonymous user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13939518/16020090)