# What are the risks of not cycling session keys in Django?

Tags: django, security, django-sessions

Django cycles the session key upon login.  The rationale (that I don't understand) is [in this pull request](https://github.com/django/django/commit/c8c159cbbad71deb4d13d6b4e10d4f38817ebdc4):

> When logging in, change the session key whilst preserving any existing
> sesssion. This means the user will see their session preserved across a login
> boundary, but somebody snooping the anonymous session key won't be able to view
> the authenticated session data.

Cycling the session key is awkward if you wish to easily associate unauth behavior with a later logged-in user. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14757138) suggests simply disabling cycle_key.

What risks are there in disabling cycle_key?  (Related to the comment above, or others.)

**EDIT**: Okay, I think I understand the rationale above.  It literally means that if you snooped unauth actions, you won't be able to associate them with auth actions.  I can see how that might be nice, but 1) ideally both unauth and auth actions are protected (e.g., https), 2) that security benefit has to be weighed with the benefit of preserving the session key.

**EDIT 2**: The pull request is from 2008, when the https landscape was way different.  [Now it's >=90% https](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/09/electronic-frontier-foundation-will-deprecate-https-everywhere-plugin/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.cycle_key) for `cycle_key` it says (emphasis mine):

> Creates a new session key while retaining the current session data.
> [django.contrib.auth.login()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login)
> ***calls this method to mitigate against session fixation***.

Hence, the reason the session key is cycled is to prevent a [session fixation attack [OWASP]](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Session_fixation). After some research a session fixation attack is basically where the attacker obtains a session id (or uses an arbitrary one) from the server and through some means (XSS attacks, MITM attacks, etc.) forces some other user to use this session id to authenticate to your server. In case the session key is not changed by the server here the attacker can now take over the users session and impersonate them.

Hence disabling this is a big risk and the returns for disabling this are also quite small. I would advice you (and anyone reading this) not to disable this builtin feature, in fact don't disable any of Django's security features without thinking well about it.

About associating unauthenticated behavior with authenticated behaviour that is better done by storing the data by serializing it in the users session itself as described in the [second method of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13939518/14991864) by [Gonzalo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1465181/gonzalo).

Comment: Thanks for this thorough answer. Very helpful. I accept it. However, I dispute "the benefit of disabling is low." The specific benefit I want is to associate (internally) the unauth session with the account that logged in. To do that, I need to use the session key as an id. The "serialize other info" method is not useful.

Comment: I'll probably have to look into "whenever someone logs in, associate their old session id with the user account in a table, and join it later somehow". That is actually quite awkward. Identity is a huge benefit. Broken, hacky, joined identity is a big pain.

Comment: Just to be explicit: since we allow a number of unauth activities, the unauth account accumulates enough state that it is brittle to keep it all in the session. We store it in the DB, keyed by session id, and when the user logs in, we want to associate all that state with the user. I understand there may be security issues there, but that's what we need to have a rich unauth experience.

Comment: Also, Wikipedia says, "Most session fixation attacks are web based, and most rely on session identifiers being accepted from URLs (query string) or POST data." I believe Django by default uses cookies (as do we). I am providing so much detail because a true evaluation of cost and benefit probably requires weighing all of this.